# Finding covariation between datasets

Tags: fourier-analysis

For me this is a very fascinating problem, which I however lack the ability to deal with as well as the nomenclature to describe properly. (Please feel free to edit the title).

**The conditions are the following:**
I have three volumes of air in which I measure the concentration of a chemical compound.
So I have three sets of data: A, B and C, which describe the variation of the compound over time. The measurements are made synchronous with equal and constant time steps.

[A](http://pastebin.com/CnAf4svk) is the outdoor air and is not influenced by neither B nor C.

[B](http://pastebin.com/dCmwx4Yn) has its own unique variation due to some internal processes, but can to some extent be influenced by A.

[C](http://pastebin.com/JpguZQV8) can be influenced by both A and B.

**The big question is:**
How can I determine which of A and B influence C and to what extent.
A complicating factor is that there is a phase shift, which may vary. It can even be the case that A and B effect C alternately or simultaneously.

I have picked up that some form of Fourier function may come in handy.
What functions and approach would be productive?

[image]

Comment: I believe you would get excellent answers on the statistical design on [CrossValidated.SE](http://stats.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @corey979 Thanks I will check it out. Never heard of that SE group.

Comment: Before all, I think you must have a look to a time series book.

Comment: One measure for this kind of thing is "coherence" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coherence_(physics)

Comment: Look for "Transfer Function Models" in books like "Time Series Analysis : Univariate and Multivariate Methods" by W. Wei.

Comment: @AntonAntonov Thank you for your advice, certainly worth looking into. In my naivety however, I imagined that, since I can scale and apply averaging functions and then visually estimate periods of coherence, there must be smarter and more stringent methods to do this in Mathematica.

Comment: @MathLind Yeah, I have in mind couple of solutions that are more straightforward. For example, we can find the lags for which the cross-correlation functions are maximized. (Some averaging might be beneficial before doing that.)